# Django error on form - ValueError: Cannot create form field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

One of my Django applications have a ModelForm based on a Model that has a ForeignKey from another app. The code is the following:

App - EstoqueGeral - models.py:

```
class ItemEstoqueGeral(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Nome do Produto")
    preco_de_compra = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, verbose_name="Preço de Compra")
    codigo_fornecedor = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name="Código do Fornecedor")
    peso_em_Kg = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=6, verbose_name="Peso (Kg)")
    quantidade_estoque_geral = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Quantidade no Estoque Geral")
    quantidade_minima_estoque_geral = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Quantidade Mínima no Estoque Geral")
```

App - EstoqueLoja - models.py:

```
from django.db import models
import ast
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Loja(models.Model):
    nome_loja = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Nome da Loja")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nome_loja

class itemEstoqueLoja(models.Model):
    item_estoque = models.ForeignKey('EstoqueGeral.ItemEstoqueGeral', verbose_name="Item do Estoque")
    loja = models.ForeignKey(Loja)
    preco_loja = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, verbose_name="Preço da Loja")
    quantidade_estoque_loja = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Quantidade no Estoque da Loja")
    quantidade_minima_estoque_loja = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Quantidade Mínima no Estoque da Loja") 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.loja.nome_loja + " - " + self.item_estoque.nome

class itemEstoqueLojaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = itemEstoqueLoja
```

And i try to use the itemEstoqueLojaForm on a view, like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from EstoqueLoja.models import Loja, itemEstoqueLoja, itemEstoqueLojaForm
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.template import Context, loader
from django.forms.models import modelform_factory
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.template import RequestContext

def editar_estoque_loja(request, item_estoque_loja):
    template = 'EstoqueLoja/editar_estoque_loja.html'
    instance = itemEstoqueLoja.objects.get(pk=item_estoque_loja)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_itemestoqueloja = itemEstoqueLojaForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form_itemestoqueloja.is_valid():
            form_itemestoqueloja.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/EstoqueLojas')
    else:
        form_itemestoqueloja = itemEstoqueLojaForm(instance=instance)
    return render_to_response(template, { 'form_itemestoqueloja' : form_itemestoqueloja }, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

But when i try to access the corresponding url, i receive a 500 Internal Server Error. On my log is the following:

```
ValueError: Cannot create form field for 'item_estoque' yet, because its related model 'EstoqueGeral.ItemEstoqueGeral' has not been loaded yet
```

I already checked my settings and everything looks fine. Both apps are on the INSTALLED_APPS and EstoqueGeral comes before EstoqueLoja. Does anybody have any idea of what could be causing that error?

Comment: First thing first, you should put your forms into a different file than the one where your models are. I have not tried your code yet, but your problem is probably caused by that.

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Django 1.6 you might be encountering this [Django bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22866)

Try importing your first model (ItemEstoqueGeral) into your 2nd models.py file

App - EstoqueLoja - models.py

```
from EstoqueGeral.models import ItemEstoqueGeral
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of a Foreign Key relation, the referenced model ("Parent Table") has to be declared first.